# Django or NodeJS for long-term web and business project?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django

Good afternoon all, we are struggling to decide which way to go for a project and would like to have some insight from people who have been dealing with this. We have to invest in training/time for the two people who are working on our business and we would like to understand which way to go.

The people
Both have a good understanding of HTML, CSS, SASS and some JS
One has some experience with PHP
One has more experience with Python

The Project

1. Database driven website that will host and display hundreds of products (laboratory products which will need specific templates for each product
2. Shopping chart for reagents and lower cost products
3. A section with a knowledge base
4. The website(s) will be multilingual, with different products for different countries
5. Integrated CRM, connected to the products, stock management and shopping chart
6. Potentially (desirable, but not necessary) an APP for the phone
7. An application that will link all the components
8. AI services and big data analytics (as a separate product)

The timeline
2-3 years, potentially 4 for completion

This is to move what we are doing manually at the moment (and what we are planning to do) to something that is kept together by a coherent structure.

We do not have much experience or funds, but we have the man hours to pour into it. Would you suggest to go with Python/Django or with JS/Node? Why?

Thnks

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Questions meant to elicit opinionated answers are specifically given as off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of data structure you need to keep if your data is kept around the world or in a central location, what kind of traffic you expect to have, and what your future of expansion looks like.

**Option 1: Stick to your strengths**

The first, and possibly the most obvious option, is to stick to your strengths. If you have someone strong in Python, Flask or Django could be the way to go because of the immense flexibility you have with python scripting, TensorFlow (for AI), and R libraries for statistical interfaces.
If only one of your 2 devs is good at python this will provide some separation of responsibility as you can have one dev focus on the page design and the other focus on the actual app functionality.

My biggest suggestion is to please stay away from PHP. Modern languages and libraries will work for what you need and are usually more reliable, less complicated, and have a whole community of active support built around them.

That being said you have to consider all the components of what you need. If your site needs are truly as large as you've described, you could break it down into microservices that handle various parts of the site independently and scale to meet traffic demands. This is all dependent on what you need of course.

**Option 2: Go outside your comfort zone**

The second, and more risky, option for you is to exit your comfort zone. NodeJS is a wildly adaptable and extensive JavaScript framework that can be molded to fit nearly any web-based need. The extensive lists of frameworks that can be used are a lot to consider, but you can deliver a more reliable, scalable, and user-friendly product with node. The HTML, CSS, and JS knowledge your team already has would be essential to making a NodeJS site work. Node also has the ability to provide you great flexibility in terms of localization. If you need to have different databases in different countries, for example, node can easily accommodate this and any other complexity you might have to throw at it. It's built to be robust and customizable for any need.

However, the drawbacks to using node are that it would be harder to implement AI and Statistical infrastructure to your site because of the nature of how node sites run. This part alone may make using python the way to go, but it can also make your site buggier, and take much longer to deploy.

**Wrapping up**

Ultimately the best choice for you is going to come down to your funding, team skills, and the systems you need to create to pull your site together. I encourage you to talk extensively with your development team to understand their strengths, weaknesses, and limits for what you need. Take their input seriously and use it to put together the best game plan possible to create the product you need.